# Get 'best-in-place' gem for rails4 from github w/o internet

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, local, best-in-place, bundle-install

I got a very limited internet connection on my office laptop and I want to install the 'best-in-place' gem. Since I use rails 4 I need to get the gem from github as far as I understood various threads. But I cant run bundle install with access outside of my local system.

Is it still possible to install that gem somehow? I already downloaded the folder form github and put it into my ruby but its not working that easy.

Best regards!

Edit: If thats not possible, does anyone of you uses an alternative gem with similar functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always clone it (or download it, as you have) and then access it later.
Let's say that you downloaded it to: /home/user3665315/workspace/best_in_place

Then, in your Gemfile you can access it locally with the :path option

```
# Gemfile
gem "best_in_place", path: "/home/user3665315/workspace/best_in_place"
```

then run

```
bundle install
```

and that's it, you have it working locally